# Opening a web page and wait for values to be updated by jquery in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'm reading the content of some web pages and I got problem with one of them which updates some values using jquery. Is there any way to read the content with a little waiting on that page?

I'm currently using `HtmlAgilityPack` to fetch web page contents.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(myUrl);

var data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("SOME-SELECTOR")?.InnerText.ToString();
```

Tried to use `BrowserDelay` but it's not really working for me.

```
web.BrowserDelay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
```

Comment: Are you needing to wait for line 2 to finish before running line 3? If so, could you use C# await to allow the web.Load() to finish before processing with line 3?

Comment: or are you saying that the html content of myUrl is not in the desired state until 5 seconds after page load?

Comment: Actually `web.Load(myUrl)` should take action then wait for 3 seconds and get the content and fill it in `doc`. So the await thing is no good for this situation. @DanSorensen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript in the retrieved web document is not being executed by HtmlWeb(). Waiting will not trigger the desired state. The JavaScript must be executed, either by your own mechanism, or by controlling a headless browser that will process JavaScript to retrieve your data.

See this related question: [Screen Scraping Web Page After Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636921/screen-scraping-web-page-after-delay) for appropriate approaches.